# Initialise all elements in an array with a value using compound literals

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, c99, gcc4

```
float myArray[myArraySize] = {1};
```

In the expression above only the first element is init with 1. How can you init all the elements with a value using a compound literals(not memset)?

I'm using GCC 4.2 on unix to compile.

Comment: @mloskot the question/answer you suggested states that `int myArray[10] = { 0 }; //all elements 0` what's different in my case? if you can only init with zero, why bother to write that instead of  `int myArray[10] = {}`?

Comment: If you have read the answers to this question, especially the highest scored one, you'd learn what behaviour to expect. So, I judged it's duplicate.

Comment: Valentin, I assumed you mean C as C89, so I skipped the features of C99. So, I withdraw the suggestion it is a duplicate. If we consider C99, then it is a distinct question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
float myArray[100] = {[0 ... 99] = 1.0};
```

is how you do it.

See [Designated Initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) in the GCC docs which says:

> To initialize a range of elements to the same value, write `[first ... last] = value'.

Comment: Argh, I forgot about this! I knew I read it somewhere in the past! Thanks!

Comment: +1, but note that this is a gnu extension and will not work with all compilers

Comment: @WilliamPursell True, but he says he's using GCC 4.2, so it works for him.

Answer (score 5):

No, only the first element will be initialized to 1.0. The rest will be initialized, but to 0.0 per the C standard. Have a look at the [C faq](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx4aa.html) for some more examples.

Comment: The accepted answer in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c question states that you can do `int myArray[10] = { 0 };` to set all elements to 0. Is the answer wrong and the elements are 0 anyway? Or it only works with 0 value?

Answer (score 2):

From the language [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **6.7.8 Initialization**
> ...
> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
> rules.
> ...
> 21 If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
> of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
> size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
> initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

`int arr[10]={1}` and `int arr[10]={0}` produce *exactly the same result* - element 0 is initialized to whatever is specified between the braces, and elements 1 through 9 are initialized to 0 based on paragraphs 10 and 21 above.  It only *appears* to be different because in one case the explicit initializer is the same as the implicit initializer.

Answer (score 0):

No you need to do them all. Those that don't get specified are given a default value, `0f` for a float.

```
float myArray[4] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
```

You may find that a simple `for` loop will result in the most maintainable code. I certainly would not encourage the use of `memset` here.

Answer (score 0):

> How can you init all the elements with a value using this formula (not memset)?

With a loop. You can't do this in a sane and portable way with `memset`.

```
float myArray[myArraySize] = {1};
for (size_t i=0; i<myArraySize; i++)
    myArray[i] = 1.;
```

It may seem ugly, but it's the C way (and it gets prettier if you rename `myArraySize` to something like `N`). Alternatively, if the number of elements is fixed, you can just enumerate the array, and optionally leave off the size:

```
float myArray[] = {1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.};
```

Answer (score 0):

Initializing any array in modern versions of C will initialize all non-specified entries to zero.

To initialize all non-specified entries to a different value, you can try memset; however, that only works very well on char arrays.

For non-char arrays, you have to write a loop.

Comment: "modern" meaning anything since 1989; you're not likely to find a C compiler that doesn't do this correctly.

Comment: @Keith, True, but now you've made me feel old. :)

Comment: *You* feel old?  My heart bleeds.  8-)}